# passing variable to terraform dynamic block v12

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am trying to use the code in this repo https://github.com/jmgreg31/terraform-aws-cloudfront/

but getting a hard time in setting the variables.

My variables.tf has this value, but somehow its not working :

```
variable "dynamic_s3_origin_config" {
default =
[
  {
    domain_name            = "domain.s3.amazonaws.com"
    origin_id              = "S3-domain-cert"
    origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/1234"
  },
  {
    domain_name            = "domain2.s3.amazonaws.com"
    origin_id              = "S3-domain2-cert"
    origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/1234"
    origin_path            = ""
  }
]

}
```

variable definition in module looks like:

```
variable dynamic_s3_origin_config {
  description = "Configuration for the s3 origin config to be used in dynamic block"
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = []
}
```

can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong here?

```
terraform plan

Error: Invalid expression

  on variables.tf line 65, in variable "dynamic_s3_origin_config":
  65:
  66:

Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a newline between `default =` and the start of the expression. Try changing your block to:

```
variable "dynamic_s3_origin_config" {
  default = [
    {
      domain_name            = "domain.s3.amazonaws.com"
      origin_id              = "S3-domain-cert"
      origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/1234"
    },
    {
      domain_name            = "domain2.s3.amazonaws.com"
      origin_id              = "S3-domain2-cert"
      origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/1234"
      origin_path            = ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is this incorrect in v12 : ${var.lambda_at_edge_arn}:${var.lambda_version}" or "var.lambda_at_edge_arn:var.lambda_version" would also work

Comment: The first one is correct. You still interpolate variables in the same way in 0.12.